# How to calculate percentage change between two years and insert in a new DataFrame in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge Dataframe that looks like this:

```
year    country     population  
1971    Afghanistan 11500000    
1972    Afghanistan 11800000    
1973    Afghanistan 12100000    
1974    Afghanistan 12400000    
1975    Afghanistan 12700000
```

I want to create a new DataFrame that will calculate the percentage difference in population, for every decade, grouped by country

```
country      1971-1980   1981-1990 1991-2000 2001-2010
Afghanistan  --          --        --        --
Australia    --          --        --        --
```

Need some help to understand how this can be done. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create decade column, then use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with `sum` and add [`DataFrame.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html):

```
d = df['year'] // 10 * 10
df['dec'] = (d + 1).astype(str) + '-' + (d + 10).astype(str)
```

Another idea with [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = range(df['year'].min(), df['year'].max() + 10, 10)
labels = [f'{i}-{j-1}' for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 

df['dec'] = pd.cut(df.year, bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)
```

---

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index='country', 
                    columns='dec', 
                    values='population', 
                    aggfunc='sum')
        .pct_change(axis=1))
```

Comment: `d = (df['year']-1) // 10 * 10; df['dec'] = (d+1).astype(str) + '-' + (d + 10).astype(str)` or use `df['dec'] = pd.cut(df.year, bins=list(range(1970, 2011, 10)))`

Comment: Thank you! this worked! I had to add the following lines to be able to view all columns and indexes properly. `population_change.columns = population_change.columns.add_categories(['country'])
population_change.columns = pd.Index(list(population_change.columns))
population_change.reset_index(inplace=True)`